# I would like to know how to create a Sprite Sheet

Tags: command-line

I have 40 images, and I would like to group them into 1 picture (sprite sheet).
4 lines by 10 column with a transparent font.

Comment: What utility are you trying to use?  You don't state the utility you are working with with `-geometry` or `-background`, so nobody can really give you assistance with it.  Or are you looking for general assistance and not help with a specific software>?

Comment: @ThomasWard I'm looking for general assistance! Thank you for asking! I just wanna do what I said in the description if its possible..

Comment: I'd remove the "I know I have to use..." bits then because that could be anything for any program - if you just need to know how to do something it'd be easier to make the question more generic that way.

Comment: @ThomasWard it's done. Any help will be really appreciated